# Unable to cast webdriver to chromedriver on using Thread guard.protect method

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am doing parallel execution using cucumber with testng, I am able to execute upto 10 threads locally without any issues, if on increasing threadcount getting timeout exception,so I have used Thread guard.protect method on creating driver instance,
On trying to access capabilities of chrome driver
((ChromeDriver)driver).get capabilities().get capability("goog:chromeOptions")

Getting error like cannot cast to class ChromeDriver(proxy41 is in module of loader app, org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver is in unnamed module of loader app)